# Jenkins seleccionar un target y ejecutar SSH en ese target

Tags: ssh, jenkins, multichoice

existe alguna manera de seleccionar una opción y ejecutar un código remoto en ese target? ejemplo: servidor1, servidor2 y servidor3; selecciono el servidor3 y se conecta a ese servidor con las credenciales respectivas para ejecutar un bash; he visto que esta la opción de "Choise parameter" y "Send files or execute commands over SSH before the build starts" pero no encuentro como vincular ambas ya que la segunda es estática seleccionando el SSH server name. Agradecería alguna sugerencia u orientación. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que encontré una manera: usando un Choice parameter nombrado como 'TARGET' con los valores de los servidores como opciones, luego en Build un "Conditional Step (multiple)" que compara dos String: ${TARGET} con el valor del nombre del servidor, tal vez hay mas maneras, por lo pronto puedo continuar :D